# AWS - How to monitor an access to 169.254.169.254

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find if someone other than me is trying to get into my instance Metadata details.

Is there a way to monitor someone trying to access 169.254.169.254? Cloud-trail? Flow-logs?
If not, any walkaround for it?

Comment: Did any of the provided answers help you?

Comment: No, I guess only AWS has this ability.

Comment: The point about IMDS is that it's a local endpoint, and is not directly reachable from off-instance. The only way for an attacker outside the EC2 instance to access it is with the assistance, deliberate or not (e.g. [SSRF](https://hackingthe.cloud/aws/exploitation/ec2-metadata-ssrf/)), of a process running on the EC2 instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

The hypervisor responds to `169.254.169.254`, so it never leaves the instance. This means that such requests stay on the instance and will not appear in any other AWS system.

You can use a firewall at the operating system level to control access, but I don't know how you'd be able to *log* such access.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [Metadata Service Version 2 (IMDSv2)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/defense-in-depth-open-firewalls-reverse-proxies-ssrf-vulnerabilities-ec2-instance-metadata-service/) for EC2. This changes how clients interact with the metadata service, adds new protections, and might resolve your core concern.

Otherwise [stefansundin/ec2-metadata-filter](https://github.com/stefansundin/ec2-metadata-filter) might be of interest. It allows you to filter which metadata keys are accessible and could probably be enhanced to monitor access.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a solution to this problem myself and was unable to find anything pre-built or via AWS services. VPC Flowlog docs mention this limitation specifically: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html#flow-logs-limitations

It is possible to track this locally so you could build out tooling to do this in a more useful way (parse logs via a datadog or cloudwatch agent or ship it out to a SIEM, etc). Here's a basic tcpdump command I used so I could analyze traffic over the course of 2 hours and then analyze that in place (replace `ensX` with the adapter used for the private IP of the instance):

```
sudo timeout 120m tcpdump -i ensX dst 169.254.169.254 | grep -E 'GET|PUT' > metadata_service_access.log
```

My use case was to see if we were over-utilizing the service (via boto or direct calls perhaps) as we've run into some problems where I believe we are hitting a throttle.